# Java Scrolling 2d Block game - Optimise my code?

Tags: java, 2d

I have a 2d game where you look down from above and can scroll up, down, left and right using a viewport and a much bigger map.

I have been having trouble drawing a rectangle around the block under the cursor but finally cracked it more through luck than anything else but ended up with this code. Can you help me optimise it and simplify it?

```
int blockwidth=gridsize-2;

//Draw coloured blocks
for (int x=0;x<sizex;x++){
   int thex=-(int)locationx+(x*gridsize);
        for (int y=0;y<sizey;y++){
        int they=-(int)locationy+(y*gridsize);                
        //if (thex>-blockwidth && thex<800){
            g.setColor(new Color( tiles[x][y][1]));
            g.fillRect(thex,they,blockwidth,blockwidth);   
        //}
    }
 }
```

Especially this piece

```
//Cursor co-ords updated       
cursorx=(int)locationx+(int)GameInput.mousex;
cursorx=(int)cursorx/gridsize;
cursorx=-(int)locationx+(cursorx*gridsize);

//Draw on screen cursor
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(cursorx,cursory,blockwidth,blockwidth);
```

Comment: "rectangle around the block under the cursor", your question isn't clear at least for me, can you please tell us in more details what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: The second piece of code works bust is very messy, what it does is take the mouse cursor position and places a square yellow rectangle under it. This is aligned with the blocks that make up the background so you can then select one of them. E.g. If there are 80 blocks wide and 40 blocks down that make up the background and each block is 20x20 pixels if the mouse cursor is at 31,21 then block 2,2 would be highlighted with a yellow rectangle around it. What I am asking is can someone suggest ways of tidying up / optimising the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three coordinate systems, all using x,y.

1. The grid/block coordinates. Each block is gridsize X gridsize pixels.
2. The world coordinates. These are grid coordinates multiplied by `gridsize`.
3. The screen coordinates. These are world coordinates minus the camera position `(locationx,locationy)`

You're asking how to tidy up the code. I think the way to start is to be use a naming convention so that you know for each x,y variable, which of these three coordinates you're using. For example, you have `thex = -(int)locationx+(x*gridsize)`. The `x` here is in *grid* coordinates, `locationx` is the camera position in *world* coordinates, and `thex` is in *screen* coordinates. When you multiply grid coordinates by `gridsize`, you get world coordinates, so `x*gridsize` in world coordinates. When you subtract the camera position from world coordinates, you get screen coordinates, so `thex` is in screen coordinates.

Consider renaming your `x, y` to `grid_x, grid_y` and your `thex, they` to `screen_x, screen_y` and your `locationx, locationy` to `camera_x, camera_y`.

The second piece of code, dealing with cursors, is similarly transforming coordinate systems. The mouse position is in *screen* coordinates. The first line is finding the *world* coordinates for the cursor. Since we know that world - camera = screen, it follows from algebra that world = screen + camera. And that's what your code does: it adds the camera (locationx,locationy) to the screen (mouse) to get world coordinates (cursor): `cursorx=(int)locationx+(int)GameInput.mousex`

The second line there is `cursorx=(int)cursorx/gridsize`. What does it do? It's taking the *world* coordinates from the previous line and converting it into *grid* coordinates. We know that grid coordinates multiplied by `gridsize` is world coordinates. Therefore world coordinates divided by `gridsize` produces grid coordinates.

The third line there is `cursorx=-(int)locationx+(cursorx*gridsize)`. You're taking the grid coordinates from the previous line and multiplying by `gridsize`, so that produces world coordinates. You then subtract the camera location, so that produces screen coordinates.

So my suggestion for those three lines of code is to be clear about which coordinate system it is:

```
cursorx_world = (int)locationx + (int)GameInput.mousex;
cursorx_grid = (int)cursorx_world / gridsize;
cursorx_screen = -(int)locationx + (cursorx_grid*gridsize);
```

To make it even clearer, you might consider using a Point class that lets you handle both x and y at once, so that you don't have to duplicate this code. You could write methods such as `toWorld` and `toScreen` to make it easier to read this kind of code.

Optimization of this part of the code is unlikely to make any difference. I'd strive for clarity over microoptimizations. (Also, I don't see a way to make those three lines much faster.)